# Limit react children to a type of <T>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Is this possible to limit children to a specific type of T with component function ?

Like this (but JSX.element is not a generic...) :

```
interface IProps {
    children: JSX.Element<IMyComponentChild>[]
}

const myComponent = (props:IProps) => { ... }
```

Comment: Day 4,769 of commenting "sadly not" to this question :P (the answer is no, sadly)

Comment: Seriously ? No solution ?

Comment: Yep there's no way to do this currently in TypeScript React. Maybe if you provided more details in another question we could find an alternative.